# Empty intersection of family of sets while being not pairwise disjoint

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is a homework question. Sadly I'm not able to find the solution by myself. This is a translation done by myself so feel free to request further information.

> Find an infinite collection of sets $M$, such that 1) $\bigcap M = \emptyset $ but 2) $A \cap B \neq \emptyset  $ for all $A,B $ $\in $$ M$.

My first idea was to modify the power set of the power set of $\Bbb N$: $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(\Bbb N)) \setminus \{\emptyset\}$.

But the problem is that while condition 1) holds and is fairly simple to construct, I always fail to meet condition 2).

The only thing I know for sure is that $\emptyset$ cannot be part of $M$ or otherwise condition 2) cannot hold whatsover.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: The sets $\{0,a\} $ with $a\neq0$ together with the set...

Comment: I replaced $\setminus\emptyset$ with $\setminus\{\emptyset\}$, which is really what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

Take $M$ to be all subsets $A$ of $\mathbb{N}$ that have finite complement, i.e. $\mathbb{N}\setminus A$ is finite while $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Could you explain why both conditions are satisfied?

Comment: @Meyu both are obvious. Write a proof and you’ll see it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two examples:

1. $M=\{(a,\infty):a\in\mathbb R$.
2. $M=\{A_t:t\in\mathbb R\}$ where $A_t=\{X\in\mathcal P(\mathbb R):|X|=2\text{ and }t\in X\}$.